# Best way to programmatically create image

Tags: python, graphics, python-imaging-library

I'm looking for a way to create a graphics file (I don't really mind the file type, as they are easily converted).

The input would be the desired resolution, and a list of pixels and colors (x, y, RGB color).

Is there a convenient python library for that? What are the pros\cons\pitfalls?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) is the canonical Python Imaging Library.

Pros: Everybody wanting to do what you're doing uses PIL.  8-)

Cons: None springs to mind.

EDIT:
in the future, we use [Pillow](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/) -- the fork of PIL.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can try [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php#python).
Last time I checked, PIL didn't work on Python 3, which is potentially a con. (I don't know about ImageMagick's API.) I believe an updated version of PIL is expected in the year.